# inner join on select without creating a view from it

Tags: sql, oracle11g

hi there I want write inner join on a select without making a view with it
like:

```
select date_,sum(t.weight)-sum(t2.miscalc) as weight from (
select decode(rownum, 1, '20201001',2, '20201005',3, '20201003',4, '20201004', 5,'20201002') as date_,
       decode(rownum, 1, 9999,2, 8,3, 9998, 4,9999,5, 9997) as weight,
       decode(rownum, 1, 1299,2, 8,3, 1298, 4,1299,5, 1297) as miscalc

from dual
connect by level <= 5) t inner join t t2 on t.date_>t2.date_
group by t.date_
```

my internal select is something like this

[image]

and i should subtract sum of all old miscals from weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do that with
with ... as clause

```
    with select * from (
    select decode(rownum, 1, '20201001',2, '20201005',3, '20201003',4, '20201004', 5,'20201002') as date_,
           decode(rownum, 1, 9999,2, 8,3, 9998, 4,9999,5, 9997) as weight,
           decode(rownum, 1, 1299,2, 8,3, 1298, 4,1299,5, 1297) as miscalc
    
    from dual
    connect by level <= 5)  as t
    select date_,sum(t.weight)-sum(t2.miscalc) as weight from t inner join t t2 on t.date = t2.date
```